# Javascript: Changing elements of shallow copy array affects original

Tags: javascript

can someone explain the reason for the behavior below?

In scenario 1 if I alter an element of the shallow copy of the array, the original array is affected.

In scenario 2 if I alter the shallow copy of the array directly by just assigning an empty array to it, it doesn't affect the original array.

What am I missing here? All I want is scenario1  to NOT alter the original array. Cant' really find an answer on this...

```
//scenario 1
var peopleOriginal =[
  {name: 'alex', age:999 }
]
var peopleCopy = peopleOriginal.slice()
var updatedPerson = peopleCopy[0];
updatedPerson.name = 'bob';

console.log(peopleOriginal) // {name: 'bob', age:999 }

// scenario 2
var peopleOriginal2 =[
  {name: 'alex', age:999 }
]
var peopleCopy2 = peopleOriginal2.slice()
peopleCopy2 = []

console.log(peopleOriginal2) // {name: 'alex', age:999 }
```

Comment: Perhaps related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Comment: As you said in scenario1 you're performing a shallow copy (not a deep copy) of the array, that means that you're cloning only the array itself, not the contained objects, when you refer to the first element of the array peopleCopy[0] you're still pointing at the same instance in memory of peopleOriginal[0].

Comment: Thanks Karim, didn't pay much attention to the "shallow" part. That answers my question, I'll try to find out how to make a deep copy.

Comment: Also **[see my post on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42045586/whats-the-difference-between-a-boolean-as-primitive-and-a-boolean-as-property-o/42045636#42045636)**, which I forgot I made and, I think, explains this clearly.

Comment: `let peopleCopy = _.cloneDeep(peopleOriginal );` will clone your element using Lodash, along with all the objects nested inside.

Comment: Try this: `var peopleCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( peopleOriginal ))`

Comment: @alexr101 Doesn't matter if it's a shallow or deep copy. An object reference is still an object reference.

Comment: @ScottMarcus just read your post. hmmm, interesting so does Js not offer a way to create a copy of an obj? It's always a reference?

Comment: @alexr101 [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) can do much of the work, but depending on how the original object is set up, it may not make a perfect copy.

Comment: @palaѕн  I don't think `JSON.stringify()` will include any inherited members and it definitely won't include methods.

Comment: @ScottMarcus That's a huge help. Apperciate it!