# Javascript - Pass by Reference in an Object using Extend (underscore.js library)

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference

In Javascript, when I use the extend function in the underscore.js library... can somebody please conceptually / visually describe to me what happens in the back-end in regards with memory - with this example:

```
var obj = {hello: [2]};
var obj2 = {hola: [4]};
_.extend(obj, obj2)
obj2.hola = 5;
console.log(obj) // hola still has a value of `[4]`
```

My issue is if I console.log(obj), for some reason, hola still has a value of `[4]`. I fully thought I would get the value 5 (via pass by reference)...

For the above example, here is what is visually / conceptually going on in my head:

1. The extend function deeply copies the key `hola` into obj:

   obj = {hello: [2], hola: *TBD*} ]btw - is obj storing only one memory address for this object?
2. Then I suspect that hola stores a memory address to the value of `[4]` (so at this point I suspect obj would be

   obj = {hello: [2], hola: *#0x93490234*}

Which is why I fully expected to see a 5 under obj.  Can you tell me what's wrong with my visualization above?

Lastly, with the explanation, can you point out how the above example is any different than the following example (I understand how / why the below example works - just not the above example and would like to hear why the below works and the above doesn't).

```
var obj2 = {hola: [4]};
var obj = obj2;
obj2.hola = 5; //console.log(obj) will say that hola equals 5
```

Comment: All arguments in JavaScript are passed by value, all the time. **[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42045586/whats-the-difference-between-a-boolean-as-primitive-and-a-boolean-as-property-o/42045636#42045636)** for explanation.

Comment: Thanks @ScottMarcus - I read the explanation in your link, but it didn't quite help me.  I don't have a function in my example / no arguments.  I'm not sure how it relates to my question - any guidance would be appreciated...

Comment: And, where exactly did you insert the `console.log()`?

Comment: You do have a function in your example `.extend()` and you are passing arguments to it. Those arguments are being passed by value.

Comment: `_.extend` **copies the properties** that `obj2` has *at that moment* to `obj`. Changing `obj2` *afterwards* has no effect on `obj`.

Comment: *" I suspect that hola stores a memory address to the value of [4]"* That is correct. But `obj2.hola = 5;` basically assigns a new memory address to a different value. `obj.hola` still has the address of the "old" value.

Comment: *"how the above example is any different than the following example"* Copying properties from one object to another is different than assigning the same object to a different variable.

Comment: @scottmarcus I'm sorry - you are right - I do have a function .extend on there.  I'm still not understanding how it relates to what you are stating.  So yes, when extend receives the obj2 parameters - it's saving a memory address to obj2 (not the value - but the memory address... so then what?)  why wouldn't obj.hola = 5 then?

Comment: `obj` doesn't have a reference to `obj2`. The *values of the properties* of `obj2` are *copied* to `obj`.

Comment: @FelixKling, thank you - however, I believe "changing obj2 afterwards" does have an effect on obj - say instead of obj2.hola = 5, I changed it to obj2.hola[0] = 5.... then if I console.log(obj) it will say that the value did change to [5];

Comment: I was just trying to help you understand that there is no such thing as pass by reference in JavaScript.

Comment: You are not changing `obj2` in that case. You are changing (mutating) the array that is assigned to `obj2.hola` (which is also referenced by `obj.hola`). Big difference! You might as well do `var arr = obj.hola; arr.push(42);` and would see a similar result.

Comment: Your use case can be simplified to the following example:  `var foo = 1; var bar = foo; foo = 2;`. I copy the value of `foo` to `bar`. Assigning *a new value* to `foo` does not magically change `bar`.

Comment: @FelixKling, I'm really sorry - I hear what you are saying and I really want to understand (no doubt - it's me, not you)... but it's not making sense to me - I'm a very visual person - and I just made this diagram - and I'm wondering if you can see where I am visualizing this wrong: https://imgur.com/a/yG8ZxIR

Comment: In your image, `hola: 0x00239245` is wrong. That would point back to the object. Instead, both `hola`s are `[4]` (or rather the address of `[4]`, which you do not have in your image).

Comment: You seem to think that the property `obj.hola` somehow points to the property `obj2.hola`. But that's not the case. `obj.hola` has a *copy of the value* of `obj2.hola`. I don't think I can explain it better than I did in my answer, but I encourage you to forget about properties first and just consider variables. Properties are like variables.

Comment: @FelixKling - thank you - this helps a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this helps:

Lets distinguish between two concepts first: **values** and *bindings*. A value is a piece of data, like a string, number, boolean, object, etc. Every value is stored in memory and has an address.

A binding is like a container or label that holds an address.

- when assigning a value to a binding we are assigning the address of the value
- when accessing a binding we get the value stored at that address

Example:

```
var a = 42;
```

`a` is a binding, `42` is a value. Lets say `42` is stored in memory at `0x1`, then `a` really holds the address `0x1`.

When we are trying to read the value, e.g.

```
console.log(a);
```

we need to look at address `0x1` to get the actual value.

Now what happens when we "assign a binding to another binding", i.e. `bar = foo`?

```
var foo = 42; // 0x2
var bar = foo;
```

`42` is stored at `0x2`. So `foo` holds the address `0x2`. When we assign a binding to another one, we simply copy the address that the binding holds. So after `var bar = foo;`, both `foo` and `bar` hold the address `0x2`. 
If I assign a new value to `foo`, e.g.

```
foo = 21;
```

then I'm making `foo` hold a new address (e.g. `0x3`).

**This does not change the address that `bar` holds.**

Exactly the same applies to object properties.

---

### Mutable values

Now you might wonder "why does `foo` and `bar` both change in the following example:

```
var foo = [42];
var bar = foo;
foo.push(21);
// bar also has [42, 21]
```

Lets assume `[42]` is stored at memory location `0x4`.

Here is how it is different to the previous example:

**We did not assign a new value to `foo`.**

Instead we *referenced* the array (at address `0x4`) *through* `foo` and *mutated* it. Mutable values are values that can be changed in place, i.e. the bits at that memory location can change.

After calling `foo.push`, `foo` still holds the address `0x4` and so does `bar`.