# Is there a way in JS to imitate 'Call by Reference'?

Tags: javascript

I think JavaScript users mostly spend their time dealing with Objects.
And for objects, we can call by reference as following.

```
let obj = { }

function f (parameter) { }

f(obj)
```

(parameter and obj refer to the same object, { })

However, I wonder if there is a way to apply this kind of work to primitive values.

```
let a = 0

function f (parameter) {
  parameter = parameter + 1
}

f(a)
```

This won't work cause a and parameter are just different variables.

Is there any way to imitate following code from C?

```
void f (int* x) {
    *x = *x + 1;
}

int main () {
    int a = 0;
    f(&a);
```

Comment: *And for objects, we can call by reference as following* [JavaScript only has call by value for both primatives AND objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42045586/whats-the-difference-between-a-boolean-as-primitive-and-a-boolean-as-property-o/42045636#42045636). There is no call by reference.

Comment: @ScottMarcus The passing of  an address of an object is what is meant by reference here. Basically, OP is trying to affect the variable outside the function's scope.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Comment: I think arrays are exceptions in this way:  say `a=[1,2,3];  b=a;  b.pop();` now a==[1,2]...  btw, to overcome that: `b=a.slice()`, and to compare arrays, if `a=[1,2,3]; b=[1,2,3];` a!=b, but `JSON.stringify(a)==JSON.stringify(b)` would return `true`.

Comment: reference in objects and arrays yes. but not sure about int/strings