# How to prevent Javascript Class variable (this) inside Methode overtakes values from variables defined inside Method

Tags: javascript

I was trying to make a small class, make a global variable inside the class and assign them a object. Inside the class inside methods i wanted to catch this values, works with them but the main object which i declared at the top i wanted to stay as it was initialized

Example Code

```js
class testClass {
  myVarObject;
    
  constructor() { }
    
  methodOne() {
    this.myVarObject = {
      blo : 7
    }
    return this;
  }
    
  methodTwo() {
    const testVar = this.getMyObject();
    testVar.blo = 12;
    return this;
  }
    
  getMyObject() {
    return this.myVarObject;
  }
}
    
let myObject = new testClass();
myObject.methodOne().methodTwo();
console.log(myObject.getMyObject());
```

The output of the console debug is:

```
Object { blo: 12 }
​blo: 12
​<prototype>: Object { … }
debugger eval code:31:9
```

What i do not understand:

Why this.myVarObject.blo is now 12 and not 7? I didn't modified this.myVarObject but only testVar.blo . I am bit confused :)

When i modify my Variable "testVar" inside the Method "methodTwo", how i can prevent that "this.myVarObject" is overtaking this new values automatically? What i wanted to do with

```
testVar = this.getMyObject();
```

is to make a copy, modify it and return it as a result. But the main Variable (this.myVarObject) must stay as it is

What i have missed?

Thank you for your help

Comment: `myVarObject;` <-- ???? This does nothing.

Comment: I don't think `testVar = this.getMyObject();` is making a copy. It's just passing the reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why `this.myVarObject.blo` is now 12 and not 7? I didn't modified
> `this.myVarObject` but only `testVar.blo`.

Yes, you did modify `this.myVarObject` when you called `const testVar = this.getMyObject();` and then called `testVar.blo = 12;`.

`testVar` is not a copy of `myVarObject`. It's a second reference to it, so when you modify `testVar`, you are modifying `myVarObject`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42045586/whats-the-difference-between-a-boolean-as-primitive-and-a-boolean-as-property-o/42045636#42045636) may be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for pointing to right direction!

While programming mostly in PHP i was not aware that variable = object is everytime a reference and not a clone.

I've solved it now with:

```
let variable = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));
```

Thank you

Comment: Your solution won't work when the object in question contains methods as `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` don't serialize object methods by default. Instead, you should use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Comment: But i understand it correctly (https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-best-way-to-deep-copy-an-object-in-javascript--cms-39655) that Object.assign() do not copy it deep down?!

My Object is like: 

let myObject = { a: { aa: 1 }, b: { bb: { bbb: 4} } }

Comment: Then you should look at a technique that doesn't cause data loss like JSON will. Check out [this](https://dev.to/shadid12/the-most-efficient-ways-to-clone-objects-in-javascript-1phe) link and look at the "Deep cloning with custom function" option.